# How to Embedd a Select in a Where in SQL Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif

I'm attempting to plug in the result of a SELECT statement into an IIF in order to change the value of another column, and having some difficulty.

In pseudocode what i'm trying to do:

```
FROM employees table select Employee IDs and their Teams
FROM employee_locations table select Locations
WHERE an employee in employee table is found in the employee_locations table, and the employee's Team is blank, retrieve their Location
IIF their location is 'USA', change the Team field for that employee to 'Data Ops'
IIF their location is 'Germany', change the Team field for that employee to 'Sales'
```

I cannot figure out why this does not work for at least the first IIF():

```
SELECT e.[ID], e.[Team]
(
select IIF(min(l.[location])='USA', e.[Team]='Data Ops')
FROM employee_locations as l
WHERE e.ID = l.ID AND e.Team is NULL
) as Location
FROM [employees] as e
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do a join on employees and employee locations to match that aspect, and then build your update query from there.

I'd make a new temporary table to hold the mappings between location and team, and also join that into the query so that it selects the new team value dependent upon location.

The following SQL would do it:

```
UPDATE (employee_locations RIGHT JOIN employees ON employee_locations.employee = employees.ID) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Temp ON employee_locations.location = tbl_Temp.location 
SET employees.Team = tbl_Temp.updateTeam
WHERE (((employees.Team) Is Null));
```

The temp table just needs two fields ("location" and "updateTeam" in my example), with two records: ( USA, Data Ops ) and ( Germany, Sales ). You can delete the temp table after the query has been run.

You could copy/paste this SQL into query builder (notwithstanding updates to match your own tables / schemas), and then click "View" (not "Run") to preview which / how many records are going to be updated when you hit "Run".

UPDATE:

To do this without a temporary table, you can use a formula within the SQL to do the mapping as follows:

```
UPDATE employee_locations 
RIGHT JOIN employees ON employee_locations.employee = employees.ID 
SET employees.Team = IIf([location]='USA','Data Ops',IIf([location]='Germany',"Sales'",Null))
WHERE (((employees.Team) Is Null));
```

But this will get tedious (and no doubt slow to execute) vs a temporary mapping table.

UPDATE II:

```
UPDATE employee_locations 
RIGHT JOIN employees ON employee_locations.employee = employees.ID 
SET employees.Team = 'Data Ops'
WHERE employees.Team Is Null AND employees.location = 'USA';
```

This is a little cleaner update query, but you'd need to run execute variations on it for each mapping you want to make.

Comment: Can this be done without having to create a temporary table? As in, could i wrap query 2 around query 1 (using the result of 1 in 2)?